# How do I round the edges of this logo in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: logo]

This is an example logo. I have the original AI file, but I want to update it such that it has has rounded edges. I also want to round the look of the arrow, but I don't know how to do any of this.

Comment: For rounded corners you are going to have to learn how to use the pen tool and point selection tool, but basically what you are going to want to do is select the corner point delete it and then curve the path between the two points to create a curved corner

Answer (score 6):

Go to the view menu and click "show corner widget. You should see these little dots appearing on the corners. You can pull them in to round the corners.

You probably don't want to round all the corners at once. So grab one or two to round with the white arrow tool. Then grab the widget.

[image: Corner Widget]

Comment: +1 because of .gif

Answer (score 0):

Rounded edges can be presented only with shading. You need more colors.

You can apply in Illustrator Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel with a round bevel.

I have only a screenshot. Thickness and rounding was easily added to it in Photoshop as layer style Bevel and Emboss. Before adding it the white background was erased and the black color was adjusted lighter to make darkening possible:

[image]

**ADD** : Actually the main color of the text can still be black, if you have light from two directions. In Photoshop's Bevel and Emboss you can use white screening for higlights and shadows:

[image]

The blue arrow can still have normal shadows. It can have the effect separately with different light and other settings:

[image]

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @LateralTerminal It's a simple how-to receipe which invites more simple how-to receipe requests to flood in. Let's see what happens when I add something that isn't as obvious.

Comment: It's sort of outside the box thinking. Actually giving it round depth instead of making it round. I thought maybe that's what the downvote was for. But I like this idea. +1